# load data from python variable into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a variable name "inventory" which has following data. How do i load the data from this variable into a pandas dataframe. If key=value exist, i want to use key as column name.

```
 print (inventory)     
 2017-05-01,pink,name=apple,quantity=6,orange,place=america
 2017-05-03,pink,name=mango,quantity=1,orange,place=europe 
 2017-05-04,pink,name=apple,quantity=4,orange,place=africa
```

Comment: What would you want to use as the column name otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame` with a comprehension

```
inventory = """2017-05-01,pink,name=apple,quantity=6,orange,place=america
2017-05-03,pink,name=mango,quantity=1,orange,place=europe 
2017-05-01,pink,name=apple,quantity=4,orange,place=africa"""

lol = [l.split(',') for l in inventory.splitlines()]

d1 = pd.DataFrame([[i for i in row if '=' not in i] for row in lol])
d2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [dict([tuple(i.split('=')) for i in row if '=' in i]) for row in lol]
)
d1.join(d2)

            0     1       2   name    place quantity
0  2017-05-01  pink  orange  apple  america        6
1  2017-05-03  pink  orange  mango  europe         1
2  2017-05-01  pink  orange  apple   africa        4
```

Comment: What about the date and color columns that aren't key-value pairs?

Comment: OP said **if** key/value pair, use as column name... so I skipped the others.  OP needs to clarify otherwise.

Comment: thanks for your response. For data which is not in key/value pair, i want pandas to give it some column name (default - 0 , 1 ,5 etc..). I can rename that later.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
inventory = \
"""2017-05-01,pink,name=apple,quantity=6,orange,place=america
2017-05-03,pink,name=mango,quantity=1,orange,place=europe
2017-05-04,pink,name=apple,quantity=4,orange,place=africa"""
content = [line.split(',') for line in inventory.splitlines()]

# prepare column names to be changed and clean the data
columns_to_be_rename = {}
for line in content:
    for i, s in enumerate(line):
        if '=' in s:
            columns_to_be_rename[i], line[i] = s.split('=')

df = pd.DataFrame(content)
df.rename(columns = columns_to_be_rename)


           0    1       name    quantity    4   place
0   2017-05-01  pink    apple       6   orange  america
1   2017-05-03  pink    mango       1   orange  europe
2   2017-05-04  pink    apple       4   orange  africa
```